# Can someone please explain to me what the "|" symbol is doing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

What does it do?

At first I thought it was a shorthand way of doing `Math.max()`
Every time I did `(1 | 0)` or `(0 | 2985235)`, I got back the larger number.
However, I was wrong, as I soon found out when I posted this question with the example:
`(128|256|0)` which does not evaluate to `256`.

Thanks for the helpful replies.

Comment: `(128|256|0)` evaluates to 384. (← comment left before the question was rewritten; original question asked whether `(128|256|0)` is a "shorthand" for `Math.max(128, 256, 0)`.)

Comment: Don't think so. And I just tried it in the console and I got 384.

Comment: Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: It's a bitwise **OR** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533387/javascript-operator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472970/whats-the-function-of-the-pipe-operator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-javascript-operators-do

Comment: Please go back to documentation, always go back to the documentation if you're unsure about something.

Comment: @Juhana Yes, my bad. Google didn't bring up many relevant results when searching Javascript and the "|" character.

Comment: @Joncom you should read this also: [What does “|=” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295469/what-does-mean-pipe-equal-operator)

Comment: That's the problem with Google - unless you know the actual name of that symbol it's hard to find a corresponding result for a question on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_%28Bitwise_OR%29) operator.
To see what it does, consider the binary form of the numbers:

```
128 = 010000000
256 = 100000000
0   = 000000000
```

The result is from performing OR bit-by-bit

```
384 = 110000000
```

I guess you might encounter this pattern in the logic to represent options.
For example,

```
128 = option 1
256 = option 2
384 = both option 1 & 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` is a bitwise operator in Javascript. So before evaluating those integers, first convert them to binary.

```
  0 -> 000000000
128 -> 010000000
256 -> 100000000
```

There might be more preceding zeros depending on your data types. Anyway `|` as a bitwise OR operator, will evaluate each bit from those two integers.

So you will get 110000000 as an result, which is 384 in decimal.

P.S. OR operation: if any one of those hold true, then true.